# How to return Page instead of List on a JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to return Page instead of List on the following native JPA query
How to handle Pageable as an argument to return a paginated list

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from foos where bar_id=:barId")
List<FooBar> findFoosByBarId(Long barId, Pageable pageable);

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_bars")
public class FooBar {

    @ManyToOne
    Foo foo;
 
    @ManyToOne
    Bar bar;
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `Page<FooBar>` instead of `List<FooBar>`.

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from foos where bar_id=:barId")
Page<FooBar> findFoosByBarId(Long barId, Pageable pageable);
```

Then you can call the method in this way:

```java
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));
Page<FooBar> page = foosRepository.findFoosByBarId(barId, pageable);
```

On the `page` variable, uou can call several useful methods:

- `page.getContent()` to retrieve the list of elements of the page
- `page.getTotalElements()` to get the number of all elements
- `page.getTotalPages()` to get the number of pages

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) the other methods of `Page` class.

Comment: My native query doesn't have parameters for Pageable, will it work

Comment: Yes, it will work because the pagination is applied over the query.

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.